# Jqgrid Selectable Headers

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jqgrid

I've a huge field list in a table in which I need to populate as a headers of JQgrid. All these headers need to be in the form of a select box (dropdown list)? How can I achieve this through JQgrid?

Thank You
Sai Krishna

**UPDATED**:

[image]

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to have. What do you mean under "headers of jqGrid"? Probably you want to use [searching toolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) having select boxes?

Comment: @Oleg: I included the picture in your main question. If you write comment to my comment and the text of your comment contain "@Oleg" text (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) for details) I would receive a notification about your answer. Now I have seen your last changes only accidentally.

Comment: @Oleg The picture is there now. Could you help me in that regard

Comment: I don't understand why you not use searching toolbar of jQuery UI Autocomplete. You will have almost the same results which you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've added the image with dropdown headers in the following image [JQgrid headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghSdy.jpg)

Comment: I tried to upload the image, but I can't see. I hope it reflects in few minutes time